# Export file format for Blender with Sound track

Tags: blend4web

I want to embed a blender object into a web application.

I want to use Blend4Web to convert it into HTML format.

a) Is it possible to dynamically configure the file path of the soundtrack (.mp3 or .wav) in HTML or JavaScript?

or

Which is the best file export format for exporting a blender object with a soundtrack included.

Please comment

Answer (score 1):

I found GLTF/GLB is the right format for exporting